# Can I split up language files in Laravel to organize my locale file(s)?

Tags: php, laravel, locale

I would really like to split up my messages.php locale file into more meaningfull files to get a better, more functional, organized set of language files. Is this in any way possible to achieve?

Thanks.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Yes you can, you only have to use the file name in the key of the message like this:

```
/app
    /lang
        /en
            messages.php
            other.php
```

In the "other.php" file:

```
<?php
return array(
    'welcome' => 'Welcome to our application'
);
```

In your controller or in a blade template yo can get the locale string like this:

```
echo Lang::get('other.welcome');
```

Like the [docs said](http://laravel.com/docs/4.2/localization#basic-usage):

> The ***first segment*** of the string passed to the get method ***is the name
>   of the language file***, and the second is the name of the line that
>   should be retrieved.

Comment: Nice.. I got it to work. I already presumed this would work this way but I didn't get it to work trying earlier on. I wonder what went wrong then.. Anyway, Problem solved. Thanks.

Comment: Dont forget to mark as solved if this response help you to solve your problem, or point up if help you a bit. Glad your problem is solved.